# want a heatmap with ticks in the center of grid blocks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid import make_axes_locatable
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

df=pd.read_excel(r'F:\testeval.xlsx')
a=df['x'].tolist()
b=df['y'].tolist()
c=df['z'].tolist()
A=np.array(a)
B=np.array(b)
C=np.array(c)
fun=interp2d(A,B,C,kind="linear")
x_cord=np.arange(min(A),max(A)+1)
y_cord=np.arange(min(B),max(B)+1)
z_cord=fun(x_cord,y_cord)
pic=plt.imshow(z_cord,extent=[min(A),max(A-1),min(B),max(B-1)],origin ='lower',interpolation='bicubic',cmap='jet',aspect='auto')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(ha="center",va="center_baseline")
plt.yticks(ha="center",va="center_baseline")
plt.title('PDT') #plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0] - 1)
#plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

[[the result i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKQI5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKQI5.png)

i want these numberings like 1 as shown in the fig at the center of the grid box
[The results that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boVMK.png)

[i want exactly these results my index number should come in the center of the grid box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlGn.png)

Comment: please show a little effort and explain your problem more than just half of a sentence in the title. What did you research? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what do you mean by the tick in the center? Do you mean instead of showing 0,1,2,3... it should show 0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5...?

Comment: i want all these numbers like 1 as shown un the center of each grid box